# Delete and Recycle Auto incremented value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In one of my database,

One table lets say "Active Records" has one column which has auto incremented value or say identity column.

Now records from that table has been removed to lets say "Deleted Records" table.

Now. I want it back to the original table "Active Records".

Is this possible to move to original table with that deleted records with its original identity?

As I want to maintain other relationships (which I have not deleted yet) with that deleted records. (This is because user might have deleted records mistakenly. So I want to allow them to recycle records)

Is this possible in any way?

Example.

I insert records in "Active Records". so auto increment value will be 1,2,3,4 and so on.

Now I delete record 2 and move that record to "Deleted record"

Now user wants it back. But if I insert that record to "Active Records" it will be 5 valued because of auto increment. But my value should retain which is 2.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would also help.

Comment: Can you share your table structure?

Comment: Use `is_deleted` flag instead. And don't "delete" anything.

Comment: I dont want to use flag. As i want to reduce main table for unnecessary records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify [`IDENTITY_INSERT...ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql) so that the provided values are used instead of an auto-assigned value. An explicit column list must be specified, which includes the `IDENTITY` column. For example:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ActiveRecords ON;
INSERT INTO dbo.ActiveRecords(RecordID, OtherData)
SELECT RecordID, OtherData
FROM dbo.DeletedRecords
WHERE RecordID = 2;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.ActiveRecords OFF;
```

Comment: Will it continue from next number after then?

Comment: The next identity value will be unchanged unless one of the inserted values exceeds the next identify value. That won't happen in this use case.